# DRF need values instead of ID

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is my serializer class

```
class ProjectSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = ['deleted_at']
```

This is Models.py

```
class MandatoryFields(SoftDeletionModel):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created",null=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_updated",null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Project(MandatoryFields, Model):  
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    project_areas = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    project_manager = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_project_manager")       
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

I am getting Id's for the foreign keys created_by,updated_by,project_manager .But I need the values instead of Id.

for example I am getting

created_by : 1

But I need 
created_by: Alex

I have tried the following

```
class ProjectSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    created_by = SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='created_by')
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = ['deleted_at']
```

But I am getting null values.

Comment: "*But I need the values of those ...*"? It looks like you forgot something in this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's achievable by specifying source attribute for serializer field

Somthing like this:

```
class ProjectSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    created_by = CharField(source="created_by.first_name")

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = ['deleted_at']
```

Reference : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source